# Merge lines from different files based on repeated first word

Tags: bash, unix, text

File 'A':

```
LoadA 1
LoadA 1.5
LoadB 2
LoadB 2.5
LoadC 3
LoadC 3.5
```

File 'B':

```
LoadA 56%
LoadA 56.5%
LoadB 73%
LoadB 73.5%
LoadC 98%
LoadC 98.5%
```

File 'C':

```
LoadA 9999
LoadA 9999.5
LoadB 4567
LoadB 4567.5
LoadC 1234
LoadC 1234.5
```

Output File:

```
LoadA 1 56% 9999
LoadA 1.5 56.5% 9999.5
LoadB 2 73% 4567
LoadB 2.5 73.5% 4567.5
LoadC 3 98% 1234
LoadC 3.5 98.5% 1234.5
```

How can I do generate the above output file using basic bash tools like sed, paste, join etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste` and `awk` you can do:

```
paste fileA fileB fileC | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $2, $4, $6}'
LoadA   1    56%    9999
LoadA   1.5  56.5%  9999.5
LoadB   2    73%    4567
LoadB   2.5  73.5%  4567.5
LoadC   3    98%    1234
LoadC   3.5  98.5%  1234.5
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include lines with the repeated start word

Comment: `awk` is merely picking some columns to print in output. It skips `$3` and `$5` since that are same as `$1`